# Second display detected but only black screen visible - Ryzen 5 4600H + GTX 1650

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 20.04, multiple-monitors

I'm using a laptop with AMD integrated graphics (Ryzen 5 4600H) and GTX 1650

- Linux 5.7.12
- Nvidia driver version 450.57 (installed via the graphics-drivers ppa)
- Secure Boot off

My external display is detected in settings and xrandr. It even turns on when connected to the HDMI port in my laptop but the only visible output is a black screen. If I remove the nvidia drivers the external display works fine but I would like to use my Nvidia GPU as well.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: @HilarieAK No, but I found out that this is a known issue and someone from Nvidia mentioned it [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/the-all-new-outputsink-feature-aka-reverse-prime/129828/10) I don't know if this was later fixed with newer drivers as I'm no longer using any linux distro on this laptop